# Used wireless as hotspot but connected device (iphone 3) gets no conection?

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, iphone, hot-spot

If got an EeePc with interenet connection via LAN.

Because I have no WLAN in my office I want to share it to my Iphone -- **although the Iphone can connect to the laptop it does not get any IPadress and or internet connection.**

- I used System -> System Settings -> Network -> Wireless -> Hotspot to establish the connection and left everything on default.
- EeePC has Internet access via LAN and gets it IPadress automatically
- the connecting device is a standard Iphone 3GS with IOS 6
- as this is a firm network IPadresses are not in standard range of an home-network
- Ubuntu on laptop is 12.04 with Unity

**Any idea what might be the problem or how to fix it?**

Please excuse if I have not given enough or the right information I am really new to the Linux world and happily will provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

One of these methods should work: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: I am aware of those but neither did work.